# Powershell and cmd environment variables

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I use a batch script to set some environment variables local to that shell. When I launch PowerShell from that command prompt, I was expecting those environment variables to be available in the PowerShell script. But I don't see that happening.

Can someone help me what I'm missing?

Comment: Where is your code? Can't help you if we can't see the code!

Comment: I was trying with '.' Keith's suggestion helped..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those environment variables should be there in PowerShell but you have to access them using the Environment provider e.g.:

```
$env:foo
```

where `foo` is the environment variable name.

Comment: Ooops.. I was trying with '.' ($env.foo) Thanks Keith.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue where I'm setting an environment variable "SETX FOO BAR /M" where BAR is the result of a query.  While I see the new/updated FOO variable correctly in the System Properties --> Environment Variables window under System Variables, I do not get the correct value under Powershell "$Env:FOO" or DOS Command Prompt with "SET FOO".  I was expecting that all environment variables would be set the same across the board.  I want to be able to query this variable as %FOO% in a GPO for setting up delegation.